# Save all changed and unchanged buffers then exit

Tags: buffers, save, quit

The command `:wqa` does not work with new files. For example, if you create some empty files and save them with `:wqa`, you will not find these files after you quit vim. They are not saved at all.

The reason is, `:wqa` only saves changed buffers (unlike `:wq`).

My question is, what is the easiest way to make `:wqa` work like `:wq` on all changed and unchanged buffers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:wa` and `:wqa` will write all *changed* buffers; from `:help :wqa`:

```
:wqa[ll] [++opt]                                :wqa :wqall :xa :xall
:xa[ll]         Write all changed buffers and exit Vim.  If there are buffers
                without a file name, which are readonly or which cannot be
                written for another reason, Vim will not quit.
```

Since your new empty file isn't changed, it's not written.

`:w` and `:wq` always writes the buffer. As far as I know there isn't a shortcut to "always write all and then exit", but you can use something along the lines of:

```
:bufdo wq
```

This will run `:wq` on all buffers, which will always write irregardless of whether it's changed or not. Since Vim will quit if the last buffer is closed, this will also quit Vim.

Comment: The `:bufdo` command sees `|` as its argument... (See `:help :bar`.) You either need two separate commands (`:bufdo w`, followed by `:q`), or `:execute` (`:exe 'bufdo w' | q`).

Comment: I think that's not really a problem @filbranden? It just calls `:q` on every buffer. Actually, you can simplify this to `:bufdo wq`

Comment: Ah yes true... There's the side effect that some buffers will be closed if you fail to write one in the middle of the sequence... But otherwise that should be fine.